# Blank Response when doing JSON POST from Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to post two **json** encoded values to my **webservice** using the below code. but i am not getting any response (Just Blank Output and No errors on LogCat).  However,  I have tried posting the same parameters from PHP to my **webservice** using **cURL** which works great.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
HttpResponse response;

try {
    json.put("name","email");
    json.put("email", "email");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");

    List<NameValuePair> ad = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
    ad.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString()));  
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(ad));
    Log.i("main", "TestPOST - nVP = "+ad.toString());
    response = client.execute(post);  
    if(response!=null) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        output =  EntityUtils.toString(entity,HTTP.UTF_8); //Get the data in the entity
    }              
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: hope you have given internet permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Getting your response by this

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
{
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're catching Exception (the super class) without logging. If an exception of any kind occurs in your try block the code will jump to the catch without any log.

Change this:

```
catch(Exception e){

                }
```

with

```
catch (Exception e)
    Log.e("myappname", "exception", e);
}
```

Comment: I think you should mention this as comment.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no response, you should definitely check your catch exception e, since you didn't write anything in the clause, there might be something happening but you didn't notice.